# what is the type of svg in d3.js

Tags: typescript, d3.js, typescript-typings

What is the correct type of svg in this d3 code:

```
const svg: any = d3.select(element)
    .append("svg");
```

?

'Selection' does not seem to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing **@types/d3**

```
d3.Selection<SVGElement, unknown, HTMLElement, any>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Selection<SVGElement, {}, HTMLElement, any>
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. This provided answer may be correct, but **it could benefit from an explanation**. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: it gives an error that Type 'Selection' is not generic.